# Why is NodeJS server twice slower than PHP server on ec2

Tags: php, node.js

I am running a simple test to benchmark the performance between PHP server and NodeJS server on t2.micro ec2 instance. The PHP server is running with tech stack Apache + PHP. The NodeJS server uses node version 14 and express. Each server does 2 things:

1. Send a JSON response through GET request.
2. Receive a POST request.

After I did some research online, I found out that the NodeJS server should be faster than the PHP server. However, my benchmark result using ApacheBench does not reflect that fact. Here is my benchmark results:

```
Start testing GET endpoint of PHP server
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1901567 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 3.15.210.36 (be patient)


Server Software:        Apache/2.4.54
Server Hostname:        3.15.210.36
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /CSE-503S-PERFORMANCE-EVALUATION-STUDY/nodejs_vs_php_server/get.php
Document Length:        196 bytes

Concurrency Level:      300
Time taken for tests:   1.213 seconds
Complete requests:      2000
Failed requests:        0
Non-2xx responses:      2000
Total transferred:      762000 bytes
HTML transferred:       392000 bytes
Requests per second:    1648.74 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       181.957 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.607 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          613.45 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    8   6.2      4      35
Processing:     8  166  30.8    171     228
Waiting:        1  166  30.8    171     228
Total:          8  174  31.3    179     254

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
50%    179
66%    190
75%    194
80%    197
90%    205
95%    212
98%    228
99%    236
100%    254 (longest request)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start testing POST endpoint of PHP server
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1901567 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 3.15.210.36 (be patient)


Server Software:        Apache/2.4.54
Server Hostname:        3.15.210.36
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /CSE-503S-PERFORMANCE-EVALUATION-STUDY/nodejs_vs_php_server/post.php
Document Length:        Variable

Concurrency Level:      300
Time taken for tests:   1.218 seconds
Complete requests:      2000
Failed requests:        0
Non-2xx responses:      2000
Total transferred:      762000 bytes
Total body sent:        496000
HTML transferred:       392000 bytes
Requests per second:    1642.23 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       182.678 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.609 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          611.03 [Kbytes/sec] received
                        397.73 kb/s sent
                        1008.75 kb/s total

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        1    8   4.8      6      37
Processing:    12  166  31.0    176     209
Waiting:        1  166  31.0    176     209
Total:         15  174  29.7    184     225

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    184
  66%    189
  75%    192
  80%    194
  90%    197
  95%    202
  98%    209
  99%    211
100%    225 (longest request)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start testing GET endpoint of NodeJS server
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1901567 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 3.15.210.36 (be patient)


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        3.15.210.36
Server Port:            3000

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        53 bytes

Concurrency Level:      300
Time taken for tests:   2.021 seconds
Complete requests:      2000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      584000 bytes
HTML transferred:       106000 bytes
Requests per second:    989.75 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       303.107 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.010 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          282.23 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0   23  11.5     20      50
Processing:    46  266  59.4    273     344
Waiting:       36  158  49.7    161     291
Total:         47  289  64.4    305     354

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    305
  66%    325
  75%    331
  80%    333
  90%    342
  95%    344
  98%    347
  99%    348
100%    354 (longest request)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start testing POST endpoint of NodeJS server
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1901567 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 3.15.210.36 (be patient)


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        3.15.210.36
Server Port:            3000

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        Variable

Concurrency Level:      300
Time taken for tests:   2.220 seconds
Complete requests:      2000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      584000 bytes
Total body sent:        372000
HTML transferred:       106000 bytes
Requests per second:    901.01 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       332.961 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.110 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          256.93 [Kbytes/sec] received
                        163.66 kb/s sent
                        420.59 kb/s total

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0   20  12.6     17      56
Processing:    20  303  89.1    310     616
Waiting:       20  160  65.3    164     383
Total:         25  322  90.3    323     653

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    323
  66%    346
  75%    385
  80%    392
  90%    406
  95%    462
  98%    466
  99%    467
100%    653 (longest request)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Looking at this results, I saw that the time per request for a PHP request (either a GET or a POST) is twice faster than the time per request for a NodeJS request.
Below is my code for the NodeJS server:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    status: 200,
    first_name: "Quan",
    last_name: "Khuc"
  })
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const { first_name, last_name } = req.body;
  res.json({
    status: 200,
    first_name: first_name,
    last_name: last_name
  })
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://3.15.210.36:${port}`)
});
```

And below is the PHP server code

GET endpoint:

```
<?php
  ini_set("session.cookie_httponly", 1);
  header("Content-Type: application/json");

  echo json_encode(array(
    "first_name" => "Quan",
    "last_name" => "Khuc",
    "status" => 200
  ));
  exit;
?>
```

POST endpoint:

```
<?php
  header("Content-Type: application/json");
  $data_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $data_obj = json_decode($data_str, true);
  $first_name = $data_obj['first_name'];
  $last_name = $data_obj['last_name'];
  echo json_encode(array(
    'status' => 200,
    'first_name' => $first_name,
    'last_name' => $last_name
  ));
  $stmt->close();
?>
```

Below is my script, I ran this script to retrieve the benchmark result:

```
echo 'Start testing GET endpoint of PHP server'
ab -c 300 -n 2000 -r http://3.15.210.36/CSE-503S-PERFORMANCE-EVALUATION-STUDY/nodejs_vs_php_server/get.php
echo '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
echo 'Start testing POST endpoint of PHP server'
ab -p data.json -T application/json -c 300 -n 2000 -r -l http://3.15.210.36/CSE-503S-PERFORMANCE-EVALUATION-STUDY/nodejs_vs_php_server/post.php
echo '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
echo 'Start testing GET endpoint of NodeJS server'
ab -c 300 -n 2000 -r http://3.15.210.36:3000/
echo '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
echo 'Start testing POST endpoint of NodeJS server'
ab -p data.json -T application/json -c 300 -n 2000 -r -l http://3.15.210.36:3000/
echo '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

What would possibly go wrong in my test? I would really appreciate any helps I could get

Comment: _"I found out that the NodeJS server should be faster than the PHP server"_... do you have any references to this _research_?

Comment: I read about the performance between PHP server and NodeJS server from here: https://distantjob.com/blog/nodejs-vs-php/#:~:text=Due%20to%20the%20V8%20engine,speed%20and%20certainly%20outperforms%20PHP.

Comment: A single post on a recruitment agency's blog does not count as research.

Comment: I learnt that the NodeJS server executes request in parallel, and the PHP server executes requests in sequentially. Should that make the NodeJS server to be faster in term of speed? I read that information from here: https://www.simform.com/blog/nodejs-vs-php/

Comment: PHP is (mostly) single-threaded for any given request but the HTTP server (Apache, NGINX, etc) and PHP worker (eg FPM) are able to handle many concurrent requests

Comment: I'd recommend reading something like this which contains a technical breakdown of blocking vs non-blocking paradigms and what each of PHP and Node.JS (and Java and Go) are capable of ~ https://www.toptal.com/back-end/server-side-io-performance-node-php-java-go

Comment: @QuanKhuc If server would execute only one request at the time, there would be no PHP usage as back-end. Yes, PHP is single-threaded, but that does not mean that you can't run multiple processes at once. E.g. FPM can have multiple PHP scripts executed at once

Comment: So in this case, does it mean that the Apache server has optimized the benchmark by executing multiple scripts at once to allow the my PHP server to have that performance?